# Could not locate cfg.xml resource [hibernate.cfg.xml]

Tags: java

Buenas gente.. me acabo de registrar en Stackoverflow, ya que tengo el siguiente problema:
Estoy tratando de insertar un registro en una Base de Datos MySql usando MAVEN e HIBERNATE.. Como Sistema Operativo tengo a Ubuntu Mate 16.04.3 LTS. Al correr mi código, ECLIPSE NEON.. me dice que no puede localizar el archivo `hibernate.cfg.xml`. Utilizo la siguiente clase para crear la sesión:

```
public class HibernateUtil {
    private static final SessionFactory sessionFactory = buildSessionFactory();

    private static SessionFactory buildSessionFactory() {
        try {           
            StandardServiceRegistry serviceRegistry = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder().configure("hibernate.cfg.xml").build();
            Metadata metadata = new MetadataSources(serviceRegistry).getMetadataBuilder().build();
            return metadata.getSessionFactoryBuilder().build();

        }
        catch (Throwable ex) {
            // Make sure you log the exception, as it might be swallowed
            System.err.println("*** Creación de SessionFactory falló." + ex);
            throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
        }
    }
    public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
        return sessionFactory;
    }
}
```

El error que me muestra ECLIPSE:

> ago 01, 2017 7:57:20 PM org.hibernate.Version logVersion INFO:
>   HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.2.1.Final} ago 01, 2017 7:57:20 PM
>   org.hibernate.cfg.Environment  INFO: HHH000206:
>   hibernate.properties not found ago 01, 2017 7:57:20 PM
>   org.hibernate.cfg.Environment buildBytecodeProvider INFO: HHH000021:
>   Bytecode provider name : javassist
>   *** Creación de SessionFactory falló.org.hibernate.internal.util.config.ConfigurationException: Could
>   not locate cfg.xml resource [hibernate.cfg.xml] Exception in thread
>   "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError  at
>   com.novellius.util.HibernateUtil.buildSessionFactory(HibernateUtil.java:31)
>     at com.novellius.util.HibernateUtil.(HibernateUtil.java:11)
>     at com.novellius.test.Test.main(Test.java:13) Caused by:
>   org.hibernate.internal.util.config.ConfigurationException: Could not
>   locate cfg.xml resource [hibernate.cfg.xml]   at
>   org.hibernate.boot.cfgxml.internal.ConfigLoader.loadConfigXmlResource(ConfigLoader.java:53)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.boot.registry.StandardServiceRegistryBuilder.configure(StandardServiceRegistryBuilder.java:163)
>     at
>   com.novellius.util.HibernateUtil.buildSessionFactory(HibernateUtil.java:23)
>     ... 2 more

Desde ya agradezco cualquier ayuda..
Como última cuestión quiero aclarar que el archivo que ECLIPSE no puede encontrar: `hibernate.cfg.xml` lo tengo en la carpeta SRC del proyecto.